# How to template like ERB in Python?

Tags: python, jinja2

[ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html), if you're not familiar with it, is the templating language used by Ruby On Rails and many other Ruby projects. In short, it allows you to evaluate raw ruby code inside HTML templates and render the result.

Consider the following:

```
#hello.erb
<html>
<body>
  <p>Hello, <%= @name %></p>
</body>
<html>
```

The Ruby instance variable @name would get replaced and rendered out onto the page seen by users.

Now, Python has a common templating language known as [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) which works in almost the same way (mostly using `{{ }}`s instead of `<% %>`s), but there's one massive difference between the two:

ERB allows you to use **any** valid Ruby code, while Jinja2 only has a very limited subset of Python-esque language, but not raw Python.

#### The question:

How do you template HTML with Python, using the entire language, rather than a limited subset?

Comment: In the future, please phrase your questions with "how do I" instead of "is there a library."

Comment: I'd say that the limitations of Jinja2 syntax are not a drawback by itself, and they were introduced intentionally. Generally speaking, putting non-trivial general-purpose code into templates is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) allows to write a regular block of Python code, like this

```
this is a template
<%
    x = db.get_resource('foo')
    y = [z.element for z in x if x.frobnizzle==5]
%>
% for elem in y:
    element: ${elem}
% endfor
```

http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#python-blocks

Comment: Thank you for getting to this before the deletionists did. Google was being massively unhelpful with this question.

Comment: And it can be called in the shell with `mako_render`. Others templating systems, like jinja for example, have to be embed in scripts and they don't have any built-in shell command.