# How to read/translate *txt.erb template (ruby) with python script

Tags: python, ruby, erb, templating

I have a quite complex software system which was developed in ruby and has been now all "translated" and transported into python. The last thing which is left is a series of *.txt.erb templates. I would like to leave them as they are but have a python library which does what the old ruby routine was doing, that is creating a series of *.txt files which follow the *.erb templates structure. I have looked a lot around but I cannot find an answer. 
Probably for a more expert python programmer this might be a simple question.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to template like ERB in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104228/how-to-template-like-erb-in-python)

Comment: The contents of the file have Ruby in them. You'd have to refactor the code to be read by whatever Pythonic pre-processor you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem changing the *txt.erb templates into *.txt files and I've coded a python script which reads the file and substitute the general variable into the specific variable I want to, for both file content and file name.
Thank you for the help!